# Issue related to JRE9

Tags: java, radio-button, rt.jar

In JRE 8, most of the internal files are present in rt.jar or tools.jar, but in JRE 9 these jar files have been removed. In JRE 8 my code was using WindowsIconFactory.class which is a part of rt.jar. Can any one suggest me an alternative class so that my code can start functioning properly again ?
(PS:My code used WindowsIconFactory.class to fetch the default icon for radio button)

Answer (score 0):

Try finding missing classes using [find jar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x)

if rt.jar is not available in jre9, download swing jars and use it.

Comment: tried searching for WindowsIconFactory but no luck...any other suggestion ?

Comment: use looks.jar http://www.findjar.com/jar/com/jgoodies/looks/2.0.1/looks-2.0.1.jar.html

Comment: Apparently there is one more class in my project (BasicComboBoxUI.class) which is a part of rt.jar, but my project doesnt throw any error while running it using JRE9, how is it able to find BasicComboBoxUI.class but not WindowsIconFactory.class ?

Comment: Dont know how they have packaged classes in jre9. I think you are using early access version. But is there any specific reason for using jre9 ?

Comment: Yes i am using early access version....no specific reason for using jre9...just trying to test whether code will work perfectly as it works with JRE8

Comment: I think its not a good idea to use until a better stable version is released.